# How to add multiple CSS files to a revealjs presentation in R Markdown?

Tags: yaml, rstudio, r-markdown, reveal.js

I am trying to put together a reveal.js presentation in RStudio using R Markdown. I want to include multiple CSS files:

```
---
title: "Slick Presentation"
output: 
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation: 
    css: "css/style.css","fonts/fonts.css"
---
```

I have tried a comma separated list of values, but the YAML parser does not appear to like this.

Comment: YAML is a file format, it has no "header" (excluding the parser directives). Might want to correct the wording to make it clearer.

Comment: @tambre Sure. I meant the YAML directives in the header of an Rmarkdown file.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what YAML directives are. [Here's](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2781147) the relevant spec section. You probably want one of [the flow node types](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2792977).

Comment: @tambre I am guessing that directives mean something specific within the context of YAML. What I meant was the pre-processing directives to knitr/pandoc in Rmarkdown documents that are specified in YAML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put the list of CSS files in square brackets, i.e.

```
---
title: "Slick Presentation"
output: 
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation: 
    css: ["css/style.css","fonts/fonts.css"]
---
```

or list the files prefixed by a hyphen, i.e.

```
---
title: "Slick Presentation"
output: 
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation: 
    css:
      - "css/style.css"
      - "fonts/fonts.css"
---
```

This is being parsed by the `yaml` package, not by pandoc.  See `?yaml::yaml.load` for a description of ways to produce a vector of strings, which is what the `css` parameter is looking for.

Comment: Perfect, was not aware that the header was being pre-processed by YAML.